# How does one configure RabbitMQ on Codeship?

Tags: rabbitmq, codeship

They claim to have the rabbitmq_management plugin enabled, but I get "sh: 1: rabbitmqadmin: not found" whenever I try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy, version 3.2.4 is installed and accessible via the default (Ubuntu) configuration. Do you need any specific settings? If so, please get in touch via support@codeship.com

(Codeship crew member speaking 😀)